# Git running a script that takes a lot of time on every startup

Tags: git

When I open my terminal for the first time after startup git runs a script, which appears on top of the terminal as git, that takes 30 or more seconds to execute until I can use my terminal. I am using Wezterm with git version 2.39.3 (Apple Git-146).

I tried looking at .gitconfig it is just my user credentials and nvim as editor. I tried removing nvim as editor issue keeps persisting.

I am using zsh on macos apple silicon

```
export ZDOTDIR="$HOME/.config"

. "$HOME/.cargo/env"
```

this is my .zshenv outside of .config and I have my .zshrc inside of .config as follows:

```
export ZSH="$HOME/.oh-my-zsh"
ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"

plugins=(git)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh


export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.zshrc
source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=$DBUS_LAUNCHD_SESSION_BUS_SOCKET"
alias t="todo.sh"  
alias firebase="`npm config get prefix`/bin/firebase"
alias air="$HOME/go/bin/air"
alias templ="$HOME/go/bin/templ"
alias tailwindcss="$HOME/tailwindcss"

alias obs="cd ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/iCloud~md~obsidian/Documents/aybars-main"

# tat: tmux attach
function tat {
  name=$(basename `pwd` | sed -e 's/\.//g')

  if tmux ls 2>&1 | grep "$name"; then
    tmux attach -t "$name"
  elif [ -f .envrc ]; then
    direnv exec / tmux new-session -s "$name"
  else
    tmux new-session -s "$name"
  fi
}
# rmd: view markdown
function rmd {
  pandoc $1 | lynx -stdin
}
function gomodrename {
    if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
        echo "Usage: gomodrename <old_module_name> <new_module_name>"
        return 1
    fi

    OLD_MODULE=$1
    NEW_MODULE=$2

    go mod edit -module "$NEW_MODULE"

    find . -type f -name '*.go' \
        -exec sed -i '' -e 's/{OLD_MODULE}/{NEW_MODULE}/g' {} \;
}
bindkey -s '^f' '~/.config/scripts/tmux-sessionizer\n'

export EDITOR=nvim
export VISUAL="$EDITOR"
export PATH="$PATH:$CARGO_HOME/bin:/Applications/WezTerm.app/Contents/MacOS:$HOME/go/bin"
```

Comment: Can you tell us anything at all about the script itself? What's in your `~/.zshrc`?

Comment: Neither git nor nvim are the culprit here. Something in one of your shell initialization files (e.g., `.zshrc`, `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, `.profile`, etc, depending on your shell) is running a git command. You should examine those files (or consider temporarily renaming them) and see if you can identify the problem.

Comment: When you start your shell, are you in a very large Git repo? E.g., did you run `git init` in your home? If that's the case, *and* one of your dot files is running a `git` command that triggers scanning a large structure, that could explain what's going on.

Comment: Hi. Check how your _shell_ initializes (on a Mac: zsh ? run `echo $SHELL` to find out). Depending on the shell, check the files larsks mentioned in his comment: zsh -> .zshrc, bash -> .bashrc,  .profile is used by all shells ...

Comment: You have a too-fancy-prompt problem like the others said.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I have appended my .zshenv and .zshrc. I am curious though doesnt .zshrc run on every new terminal initialized. I am only experiencing this slowdown on only the very initial time when I open my terminal after startup.